# 催 vs 促使 - cui vs cushi

Tags: vocabulary

So, the difference between these two. Am I right in believing that 催 is to encourage/urge a third party to do something *quicker/with more haste*, whereas 促使 is to encourage/urge someone to do something *at all*?
圣诞快乐!
Hashamyim / 罗云

Comment: 促使 to cause someone to do something; 催 to cause someone to do something earlier or quickly

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask the difference between 催促 vs 促使?

Comment: I'm happy to ask that, but my vocab list only states 催 and not 催促. But anyway, what is the difference between 催促 and 促使? (I'm hoping that this is the setup for a really good joke :-))

Comment: see dictionaries, e.g.促使 https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E4%BF%83%E4%BD%BF (users may conclude that
no human actors need be explicitly involved)
催 https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E5%82%AC (En follows Ru )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 催: to urge; to harry (*someone to do something*)
>
> 促使: to motivate; to cause; to prompt (*someone to do something or something to happen*)

**'催' has to be with intention**. e.g.  in "我催他快點出門" ( I urge/ hurry him to go out sooner). 'I' have the intention of 'urging him to go out sooner'

**'促使' has to be with a cause**. e.g. in "前蘇聯的威脅促使北約成立" (The threat of the former Soviet Union prompted the establishment of NATO) '前蘇聯的威脅' is the cause of 'the establishment of NATO'

Note 1: '我' is the subject that applies the verb 'to hurry', it is not the cause of '他快點出門'. *the subject must have an intention to apply the verb 催*

Note 2: there is no intention in '前蘇聯的威脅' to cause NATO to form.

Answer (score 3):

促使: *make something happen*;

催（促）: *To urge sb.*;

The normal collocations would be *促使 + **something*** and *催(促) + **somebody(+something) or bare***. Eg:

> 别催我，好吗？
>
> 别催了，行吗？
>
> 他天天催我给他买飞机票。
>
> 深厚的友谊促使大家携手前进。